# Date and time formatting

Tags: c#, string-formatting

How do I convert a date time value in a C# application into a string that has the form `6-18-2012 13:12:13.0`? I keep getting leading zeros. In addition, I can't seem to get it into military time.

Comment: can you share what you are trying?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
myDateTime.ToString("M-d-yyyy HH:mm:ss.f")
```

If you don't want any leading zero on the hour, either, do this:

```
myDateTime.ToString("M-d-yyyy H:mm:ss.f")
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
date.ToString( "M-d-yyyy H:mm:ss.f" );
```

That string will not add a leading 0 to the month, day, or hour. More information can be found at Microsoft's [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: +1 for the link. I always forget the different options and have that link bookmarked

Answer (score 1):

You can too use:

`string.Format("{0:M-d-yyyy H:mm:ss.f}", yourDateTime);`

More details in [C# Examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Comment: I like this answer, because it starts to point out another thing about these format strings: They are the similar for `String.Format()` and `.ToString()`, except the `{0:...}` isn't required for `.ToString()`.